# WGS 84 terrain import to SketchUp

Tags: qgis, wgs84, mesh, sketchup

I am trying to create a 3D terrain map in Sketchup, based on a DEM file from the UK LIDAR series. I can add the DEM to QGIS as a raster layer and then use DEMto3D to produce a mesh in `.stl` format which can be imported to Sketchup. Then the plan is to use Modelur to import features created as Shapefiles to sit on the terrain.

My problem is that Modelur will only import Shapefiles to Sketchup in WGS 84 coordinates, but the `.stl` mesh has CRS EPSG:27700 inherited from the UK LIDAR DEM. So the Shapefile features do not align with the terrain.

I have tried using QGIS to reproject the DEM to WGS 84 before using DEMto3D, but the resulting mesh is chaotic. I think DEMto3D does not work with WGS 84.

Does anyone know how to create a 3D mesh from a DEM in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use use the warp(reproject) processing tool to convert the DEM to WGS84 before converting to STL format.

Comment: How is that different from the `I have tried using QGIS to reproject the DEM to WGS 84 before using DEMto3D` mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you just changed the projection in the file properties, and that was why the mesh was chaotic as that method doesn't actually reproject the layer and should only be used if qgis is using an incorrect projection

Comment: Not me, I didn't ask the question.